# Single product page have slow loading

Tags: database, query, slow-response

When I open the single product URL (open product). I wait 8 seconds or more for the page to load. Responsible for this behavior is the amount of queries that magento is performing. For this I enabled slow_query_log as on.

Below I leave the link to the entire log generated when I open the page of any product. https://pastebin.com/iu4fyFiL

Note that there will be seven slow in this same log and the queries appear to be exactly the same. There are some that are really the same and I have no idea why that happens. One contains `AND (product_id IN (1240))` and the other contains`(cpe.entity_id = '1624')`.

I do not understand how this is possible. I took some support in this store and I see that queries are closely linked with this part of the front end whose same I don't know if it's a plugin or something of magento itself.

Does anyone know what's up?

Comment: is it in your local server?

Comment: No, this is production mode. I have this in two server.

Comment: so can you share me the details so I can check it.

Comment: If you pass your email i can share more details like URL´s.

Comment: hope you seen my profile